# AJAX request displaying content to user but not on the source of the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

On the body of the document, lets call it "form.php" we have the following:

On the `head` we have a JavaScript code:

```
<script>
  function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    } else {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "getchauffeur.php?q=" + str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  }
</script>
```

We query to database and populate a dropdown. We switch  content using (`showUser`):

```
<div>
  <? 

  $result = $mysqli -> query("select id, nomchauffeur from  chauffeurs");
  echo "<select name='id'  onchange='showUser(this.value)'>";

  while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {

      unset($id, $name);
      $id = $row['id'];
      $name = $row['nomchauffeur'];
      echo '<option value="'.$id.
      '">'.$name.
      '</option>';
  }

  ?>
```

Here we are still in body. We put the content of AJAX into `div`.

```
  <div id="txtHint"><b>chauffeur info will be listed here...</b> </div>

</div>
```

Here is our script that populate form fields with the content of AJAX request:

```
<script>
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
      //rIndex = this.rowIndex;

      document.getElementById("nomchauffeur").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("prenomchauffeur").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("agechauffeur").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("cinchauffeur").value = this.cells[3].innerHTML;

    };
  }
</script>
```

Now here is our getchauffeur.php:

```
<?php

  $q = intval($_GET['q']);

  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','nouveau');
  if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

  mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax");
  $sql="SELECT * FROM chauffeurs WHERE id = '".$q."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  echo "<table>
  <tr>
    <th>nom</th>
    <th>prenom</th>
    <th>age</th>
    <th>adresse</th>

  </tr>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['nomchauffeur'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['prenomchauffeur'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['agechauffeur'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['adressechauffeur'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**The Problem:**  Everything works fine if the table is on the same page. But here the AJAX request constraints us to put the table in other php page(chauffeur.php).
What we need is populating the form fields automatically by clicking on the row displayed from dropdown `Change` actions. It appears that the row inserted into table inside 'chauffeur.php' is not printed on the html `DOM`. When we click on page view source, it displays only:

```
<div id="txtHint"><b>chauffeur info will be listed here...</b> </div>
```

And not the content of the following fields:

```
nomchauffeur  prenomchauffeur  agechauffeur adressechauffeur
```

How could we grab the content of row and fill automatically the form and where is it?

Comment: Check in your network what response are you getting on your request when drop-down changes.

Comment: getchauffeur.php?q=1  getchauffeur.php?q=2  getchauffeur.php?q=3

Comment: <table>
 <tr>
<th>nom</th>
<th>prenom</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>adresse</th>

</tr><tr><td>chaugffeur1</td><td>prenomc1</td><td>23</td><td>adressec1</td></tr></table>

Comment: So, your response is correct. just see if you're getting it under response text.

Answer (score 0):

This whole javascript AJAX should be after your HTML div #txtHint.

`if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
 }`
Also you can return only row instead of whole table. On main page create table as id 'txtHint' and insert that row in response.

Comment: No results. I see the row as a user. i click on the row to populate fields of the empty form but nothing happens. but the view page source give the following:       <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
<script type="text/javascript">if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
 }</script>

Comment: Give id 'table' to your <table>.

Comment: still no results.  sorry

Comment: below  the link of the two files. thanks in advance for your support.                            http://iglobaldev.co.nf/iglobaldev.txt